# Convert time decimal to datetime object python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert a decimal time to a datetime object to look for the months in order to later divide the time into seasons. I did some research and stumbled upon datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp but everything I have tried produces the following error:

```
                 TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
```

In the past, I have used pandas to create a new time array, but do not feel that is best for my given situation. Currently I have the following in my code and tried doing it without the for loop as well, in hopes that I can get fromtimestamp() to work correctly.

```
raw_time = (data.variables['time'].getValue()/float(365*24))+1800 #hours since 1800
time = n.where((raw_time>=2006)&(time<=2016)) #our specific time interval

annual_time = []
for i in raw_time[time]:
    annual_time.extend(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i))
```

My time was read in from as netCDF file and currently appears as follows:

```
print raw_time[time]
array([ 2006.05205479,  2006.1369863 ,  2006.22191781,  2006.29863014,
    2006.38356164,  2006.46575342,  2006.55068493,  2006.63287671,
    2006.71780822,  2006.80273973,  2006.88493151,  2006.96986301,
    2007.05205479,  2007.1369863 ,  2007.22191781,  2007.29863014,
    2007.38356164,  2007.46575342,  2007.55068493,  2007.63287671,
    2007.71780822,  2007.80273973,  2007.88493151,  2007.96986301,
    2008.05205479,  2008.1369863 ,  2008.22191781,  2008.30136986,
    2008.38630137,  2008.46849315,  2008.55342466,  2008.63561644,
    2008.72054795,  2008.80547945,  2008.88767123,  2008.97260274, ...])
```

Comment: How is the time represented using the number - 2006 is what and after the decimal(05205479) is what  ?

Comment: 2006 is my starting year and the decimal afterwards is the month stamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [netCDF4 num2date](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.num2date) to convert `time` from numeric values to datetime objects.

```
import netCDF4

ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('./foo.nc', 'r')
time = ncfile.variables['time'] # do not cast to numpy array yet 
time_convert = netCDF4.num2date(time[:], time.units, time.calendar)
```

This will create a `time_convert` array of datetime objects that you can then work with to generate seasons, for example.

Comment: This worked out perfectly and actually shortened my code! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is because of your use of `extend`:

```
annual_time = []
for i in raw_time[time]:
    annual_time.extend(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i))
```

*list*`.extend()` is used to take another list or iterable and add its contents to the end of the list.  `datetime` does not return a list or iterable; it returns a datetime instance.  For scalar values, you need to use `append`:

```
annual_time = []
for i in raw_time[time]:
    annual_time.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i))
```

Having said that, I think you will need to manipulate the time values before using this function, because the values you are giving do not look like timestamps (which are a number of seconds past January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC) - unless those times really are supposed to be about half an hour after midnight January 1, 1970...

Comment: My decimals are months starting at January 1948. So 2006.0520... is January 2006,  2006.1369... is February 2006,  2006.2219... is March 2006, etc. The day within the month or time of day is irrelevant to me for this specific circumstance. I am trying to convert it to a datetime object (if possible) so I can later search by month rather than by a decimal. Is there a different function I can use rather than fromtimestamp? I personally have not been able to find anything.

Comment: If you don't care about the time, you can just use the `date` class instead of the `datetime` class.  Either way you choose to go, you will need to parse out the year, month, and date and feed directly into the class constructor, rather than using one of the factory methods:  `annual_time.append(datetime.date(year,month,dayofmonth))`